# How to make first option in dynamic select as blank?

Tags: jquery, laravel

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer to fit my specific code.

I have a dynamic drop-down list for customers. When a customer is chosen, it populates the customer contacts. That all works great. However, it places the first option with the first value from the database and I want it blank to force people to choose the correct contact.

Here is my code:

```
 $('select[name="customer"]').on('change', function(){

    var customerId = $(this).val();

    if(customerId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/customer/contacts/get/'+customerId,
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"json",
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#loader').css("visibility", "visible");
            },

            success:function(data) {

                $('select[name="customer_contact"]').empty();

                $.each(data, function(key, value){

                    $('select[name="customer_contact"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">' + value + '</option>');

                });
            },
            complete: function(){
                $('#loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('select[name="customer_contact"]').empty();
    }

});
```

And here is the select where the customer populates:

```
            <select
                            name="customer_contact"
                            class="form-control shadow">
                            <option>

                            </option>

                        </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can basically add a blank value or a "Choose Contact" option before you append your data from the database. Since i'm unable to recreate this snippet right now. I'd suggest you try adding the below code

```
$('select[name="customer_contact"]').append('<option value="Choose">Choose Contact</option>');
```

So you full code would be as seen below

```
 $('select[name="customer"]').on('change', function(){

    var customerId = $(this).val();

    if(customerId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/customer/contacts/get/'+customerId,
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"json",
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#loader').css("visibility", "visible");
            },

            success:function(data) {

                $('select[name="customer_contact"]').empty();

$('select[name="customer_contact"]').append('<option value="Choose">Choose Contact</option>');

                $.each(data, function(key, value){

                    $('select[name="customer_contact"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">' + value + '</option>');

                });
            },
            complete: function(){
                $('#loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('select[name="customer_contact"]').empty();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code just appends the new options to the existing select, so if you put the blank option in there first, it will still be available:

```
<select
    name="customer_contact"
    class="form-control shadow">

    <option value="" selected>Please select...</option>

</select>
```